# How to make function unique in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Okay, so I have to make a function called unique. This is what it should do:

If the input is: s1 = [{1,2,3,4}, {3,4,5}] 
unique(s1) should return: {1,2,5} because the 1, 2 and 5 are NOT in both lists.

And if the input is s2 = [{1,2,3,4}, {3,4,5}, {2,6}]
unique(s2) should return: {1,5,6} because those numbers are unique and are in only one list of this collection of 3 lists.

I tried to make something like this:

```
    for x in s1:
        if x not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(x)
        else:
            unique_list.remove(x)

print(unique_list)
```

But the problem with this is that it takes a whole list as "x" and not each element from each list.

Anyone that can help me a bit with this?
I am not allowed to import anything.

Comment: Why would you add python-3.x and python-2.7 in your tags? Please remove one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python `set()` objects have a [`symmetric_difference()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) method to find elements in either, but not both sets. You can reduce your list with this to find the total elements unique to each set:

```
from functools import reduce

l = [{1,2,3,4}, {3,4,5}, {2,6}]

reduce(set.symmetric_difference, l)
# {1, 5, 6}
```

You can, of course do this without `reduce` by manually looping over the list. `^` will produce the `symmetric_difference`:

```
l =  [{1,2,3,4}, {3,4,5}, {2,6}]

final = set()
for s in l:
    final = final ^ s
print(final)
# {1, 5, 6}
```

Comment: OP said "I am not allowed to import anything".

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 4):

```
In [13]: def f(sets):
    ...:     c = {}
    ...:     for s in sets:
    ...:         for x in s:
    ...:             c[x] = c.setdefault(x, 0) + 1
    ...:     return {x for x, v in c.items() if v == 1}
    ...:

In [14]: f([{1,2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}])
Out[14]: {1, 4}
```

Comment: Where are you getting `Counter()`? Also, OP said "I am not allowed to import anything".

Comment: You are right, I did "from collections import Counter", and didn't notice the limitation on importing. I will revise my answer.